# Value for the fields which are tab delimited in csv file

Tags: xml, csv, xml-parsing

I have to read a data from the csv file  rite now I am reading a data from csv file 
using the CSVBeans 0.7 (CSVBeans allows to map your Java objects with information stored in CSV format.)

For more information on csv beans 0.7 please refer to this url..http://www.jroller.com/fouadhamdi/entry/csvbeans_0_5

Now my query is that I have one csv file that I have parsed was like this

`aa.txt`:

```
AAA|BBB|CCC|DDD
22|33|44|55
```

As you can see that it the values are seprated by pipe delimeted , I have made seprate
mapping file for this in xml (used for csv beans 0.7)

```
<csvbeans>
    <strategy>
        <parser className="org.csvbeans.parsers.CSVParser"/>
    </strategy>
    <property name="separator" value="|" />
    <property name="noStartTag" value="true" />
    <converters>
```

Now I have to parse another csv file but it is tab delimited , below is the content

`bb.txt`:

```
AAA BBB CCC DDD
45  76  87  98
```

As you can see that the above file values are septaed by tab , (tab generally seen as white apace but if we explore it in a editior like textpad then we can see the special character used in pace of tab )

Now please advise me for tab delimed which special character we are goiong to use so that I can tell the xml that the contents in the csv file is delimeted by tab

```
<property name="separator" value >
```

folks please advise.!

Comment: well guys let me know \t will work

Answer (score 0):

Try with a `"\t"` as the character separator.